# Generated a mirror of a site using php

Tags: php

I want to do the following : when the user access www.mysite.com, i want the server dynamically fetches the content of another site (let's say www.othersite.com) and generate the same html output for www.mysite.com.

So when the user goes to www.mysite.com, he will see exactly the same as he would see on www.othersite.com. This need to work also with www.mysite.com/myfolder, www.mysite/myotherfolder and so on.

I know i could use a redirect on .htaccess to do that, but for study purposes i want do that using only PHP.

Is there a way ?

Comment: What is the problem you have in doing so what you want to do? Please edit your questions to include your source code and/or attempts you have.

Comment: @Progman I have no code because i really don't know how to do that :0

Comment: I would be careful with this. Depending on the site, it could constitute plagiarism or other infringement.

Comment: @RussJ No problem, the source site is also mine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the target site's html code f.e. with `file_get_contents` and then just `echo` it out:

```php
<?php
$htmlContent = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com');
echo $htmlContent;
```

But this won't fix the links in it, f.e. when the page has a `<a href="/somepage.html">Click</a>` and you click on it on your mirrored site, it will point to a non existing script on your server.

You could replace all links with `preg_replace` to point to your script with a query parameter of the target.